# Merge grid columns

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, grid

Hi I've been searching for a solution with no success ...

I want a grid that resembles:

```
+-------+----------------+
|       |                |
+-------+----------------+
|                        |
|                        |
|                        |
+-------+----------------+
|       |                |        
+-------+----------------+
```

Thank you in advance!

Answer (score 51, accepted):

It looks like a 3-row, 2-column Grid with proportional sizes:

```
<Grid>
    <Grid.RowDefinitions>
        <RowDefinition Height="*" />
        <RowDefinition Height="2*" />
        <RowDefinition Height="*" />
    </Grid.RowDefinitions>
    <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
        <ColumnDefinition Width="*" />
        <ColumnDefinition Width="3*" />
    </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
</Grid>
```

The 5 cells would be like:

- **Top-left**:      Grid.Column="0", Grid.Row="0"
- **Top-right**:     Grid.Column="1", Grid.Row="0"
- **Center**:        Grid.Column="0", Grid.Row="1", Grid.ColumnSpan="2"
- **Bottom-left**:   Grid.Column="0", Grid.Row="2"
- **Bottom-right**:  Grid.Column="1", Grid.Row="2"

Answer (score 23):

Now, that is a very simple grid. Two columns and three rows with the second row content spanning two columns... it doesn't get much simpler than that...

```
  <Grid Width="640" Height="480">  
    <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
      <ColumnDefinition Width="3*"/>
      <ColumnDefinition Width="7*"/>  
    </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
    <Grid.RowDefinitions>
      <RowDefinition Height="25*"/>
      <RowDefinition Height="50*"/>
      <RowDefinition Height="25*"/>
    </Grid.RowDefinitions>
  <Border Grid.Column="0" Grid.Row="0" BorderBrush="Red" Margin="1" BorderThickness="2" HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" VerticalAlignment="Stretch"/>
  <Border Grid.Column="1" Grid.Row="0" BorderBrush="Green" Margin="1" BorderThickness="2" HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" VerticalAlignment="Stretch"/>
  <Border Grid.Column="0" Grid.Row="1" Grid.ColumnSpan="2" Margin="1" BorderThickness="2" BorderBrush="Blue" HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" VerticalAlignment="Stretch"/>
  <Border Grid.Column="0" Grid.Row="2" BorderBrush="Red" Margin="1" BorderThickness="2" HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" VerticalAlignment="Stretch"/>
  <Border Grid.Column="1" Grid.Row="2" BorderBrush="Green" Margin="1" BorderThickness="2" HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" VerticalAlignment="Stretch"/>
  </Grid>
```

[image]

Answer (score 2):

Super late answer, sorry. Hopefully it will help someone who is looking for it in the future, like I am. In looking for an answer to the same question, I stumbled across this:

```
<Grid>
    <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
        <ColumnDefinition Width="*"/>
        <ColumnDefinition Width="3*"/>
    </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>

    <Grid.RowDefinitions>
        <RowDefinition Height="*"/>
        <RowDefinition Height="2*"/>
        <RowDefinition Height="*"/>
    </Grid.RowDefinitions>

    <Border Grid.Row="1"
            Grid.ColumnSpan="2">
        <!-- Code -->
    </Border>
</Grid>
```

The main portion of that being 'Grid.ColumnSpan="2"'